# Setting local port for making requests with Symfony HttpClient

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to employ [CURLOPT_LOCALPORT](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_LOCALPORT.html)/[CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE.html) features to setup Symfony HttpClient? I have a requirement of sending requests from a range of local ports. Can't see any suitable options available here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.0/src/Symfony/Contracts/HttpClient/HttpClientInterface.php

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the curl library enabled on your system, the default [`HttpClient::create()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpClient/HttpClient.php) appears to use the [`CurlHttpClient`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpClient/CurlHttpClient.php). The CurlHttpClient sadly [sets the curl parameters](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4a365d2cf28709d40a2c0f884fd1447318ee6eed/src/Symfony/Component/HttpClient/CurlHttpClient.php#L301) from a separate variable `$curlOpts` which **no custom options** can be written to, in this particular function (read code for details).

So, one reasonable approach would be to implement your own `CurlHttpClient` (meaning: copy), add another option to set the curl options you want, avoiding `HttpClient::create()` (or whatever incantation you use) and instead instantiate your own client for your tests.